# How to remove word break and line break in pdf file?

Tags: ruby, pdf

I'm trying to parse a pdf file and I would like to get an input without word break at the end of the line, ex :

**text.pdf**

```
"hello guys I ne-
ed help"
```

How to remove the "-" and the line break in order to stick the both part of "need" together

This is my actual code :

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(‘text.pdf’)
reader.pages.each do |page|
 page.text.each_line do |line|
   words = line.split(” “) # => ["hello"], ["guys"], ["I"], ["ne-"], ["ed"], ["help"]
    words.each do |word|
      puts word
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String#`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub):

```
a = "hello guys I ne-
ed help"
#=> "hello guys I ne-\n" + "ed help"
a.gsub(/-|\n/, '-' => '', "\n" => '')
#=> "hello guys I need help"
```

With your code:

```
reader = PDF::Reader.new(‘text.pdf’)
reader.pages.each do |page|
  page.text.each_line { |line| line.gsub(/-|\n/, '-' => '', "\n" => '')}  
end
```

Or, if dash and new line element are always together substitute them together:

```
a.gsub(/-\n/, '')
#=> "hello guys I need help"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried the first proposition and this removed the "-" but I still get the "ed" on an other line. May be line break in pdf have to be managed differently ?

Comment: @Orsay did you try the second one? Though, I think it wouldn't differ much

Comment: Yes I tried the second one but it keep the dash and the line break

Comment: @Orsay beware, that `each` returns the original collection. To see if it works use the following: `page.text.each_line { |line| puts line.gsub(/-|\n/, '-' => '', "\n" => '')}`. This way you'll see the resulting strings.

Comment: Still not. I aslo tried in doc format. The second part of the word still stay on an other line

Comment: I inspected  the result and it appears that the both part of the sentence are 2 different string : "hello guys I ne"
"ed help"

Comment: @Orsay that's probably the reason you did not get expected result :D I think you should come up with something merging two lines if they are broken with `/-\n/`. But I am not an expert in text processing TBH

Comment: Ok I get it, I need to join the results. The issue now is with first proposition I get all the "-" of my text deleted (I don't want that) and with the second I get the /n deleted but not the "-". How to get both dash and /n deleted. The second proposition seems to be the best but not working correctly :/

Comment: @Orsay second should remove dash **only** if it is followed by new line character `\n`...

Comment: It doesn't delete dash at all, even the ones followed by /n . But you help me to go further anyway so thank you :)